# How to run a JAR file

Tags: java, jar

I created a JAR file like this:

```
jar cf Predit.jar *.*
```

I ran this JAR file by double clicking on it (it didn't work). So I ran it from the DOS prompt like this:

```
java -jar Predit.jar
```

It raised "Failed to load main class" exceptions. So I extracted this JAR file:

```
jar -xf Predit.jar
```

and I ran the class file:

```
java Predit
```

It worked well. I do not know why the JAR file did not work. Please tell me the steps to run the JAR file

Answer (score 250):

You need to specify a Main-Class in the jar file manifest.

Oracle's [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) contains a complete demonstration, but here's another one from scratch. You need two files:

Test.java:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
```

Note that the text file must end with a new line or carriage return.
The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a
new line or carriage return.

Then run:

```
javac Test.java
jar cfm test.jar manifest.mf Test.class
java -jar test.jar
```

Output:

```
Hello world
```

Comment: if Test class refers another class via jar file, in that case what modifications to be done?

Comment: @Anand then you need to include a Class-Path line in your manifest and reference the other jar(s).  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: Please Help me on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740803/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-on-jar-executing

Comment: I think having Manifest-version: 1.0 is not necessary because the contents of the given manifest file get appended to the default manifest file that already has the version http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: you need put in the manifest "Main-Class: Test" only. Also an important here is to pass to new line after this string and to save. Otherwise  it will create default manifest inside the jar without declaring main class.

Comment: This is just end-to-end sample. Perfect simple crisp. I was looking for something like this for hours. Not sure why whole Internet is full with all junk without such an simple example, when searched for How to create "Hello world" java jar. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 70):

```
java -classpath Predit.jar your.package.name.MainClass
```

Comment: If this jar uses other jars, shouldn't the classpath be like "/path/to/jars/*" ?

Comment: @Max Chetrusca Yes but the separator is `:` using `*` will not work because your shell will expand it like this: `"/path/to/jars/a.jar" "/path/to/jars/b.jar"` but what you really want is: `"/path/to/jars/a.jar:/path/to/jars/b.jar"`.

Answer (score 54):

Before run the jar check `Main-Class: classname` is available or not in **MANIFEST.MF** file. MANIFEST.MF is present in jar.

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

Answer (score 22):

You have to add a manifest to the jar, which tells the java runtime what the main class is.
Create a file 'Manifest.mf' with the following content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: your.programs.MainClass
```

Change 'your.programs.MainClass' to your actual main class. Now put the file into the Jar-file, in a subfolder named 'META-INF'. You can use any ZIP-utility for that.

Comment: Just of of curiosity, is the 'Meta-inf' subfolder name case sensitive? I have traditionally seen it spelled 'META-INF'

Comment: You're right. The spec says "META-INF" and does not say anything about case insensitivity (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#The%20META-INF%20directory)

Answer (score 20):

A very simple approach to create .class, .jar file.

Executing the jar file. No need to worry too much about manifest file. Make it simple and elgant.

**Java sample Hello World Program**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

**Compiling the class file**

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

**Creating the jar file**

```
jar cvfe HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class
```

or

```
jar cvfe HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld *.class
```

**Running the jar file**

```
 java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

Or

```
java -cp HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld
```

Comment: Yes, the `jar`'s option `e` lets you specify the `Main-Class` (*entrypoint*) and also creates a corresponding manifest file for you. See [the official documentation for jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html).

Comment: I tried using a manifest and entry point with no success, until I tried creating the class file first as you mentioned. <3

Answer (score 11):

If you don`t want to create a manifest just to run the jar file, you can reference the main-class directly from the command line when you run the jar file.

```
java -jar Predit.jar -classpath your.package.name.Test
```

This sets the which main-class to run in the jar file.

Comment: `-classpath` comes right after `java` and get rid of `-jar` (i.e. this answer is incorrect)

Answer (score 4):

Java

```
class Hello{
   public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("Hello Shahid");
   }
}
```

manifest.mf

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: Hello
```

On command Line:

```
$ jar cfm HelloMss.jar  manifest.mf Hello.class 
$ java -jar HelloMss.jar
```

Output:

```
Hello Shahid
```

Answer (score 4):

**Eclipse Runnable JAR File**

*Create a Java Project – `RunnableJAR`*

- If any [jar files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) are used then add them to project build path.
- Select the class having main() while creating Runnable Jar file.
  [image]

*Main Class*

```
public class RunnableMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Name : "+args[0]);
        System.out.println(" ID  : "+args[1]);
    }
}
```

*[Run Jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) file using java program ([cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)) by supplying arguments and get the output and display in eclipse console.*

```
public class RunJar { 
    static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jarfile = "D:\\JarLocation\\myRunnable.jar";
        String name = "Yash";
        String id = "777";

        try { // jarname arguments has to be saperated by spaces
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe start /C java -jar "+jarfile+" "+name+" "+id);
                    //.exec("cmd.exe /C start dir java -jar "+jarfile+" "+name+" "+id+" dir");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream ()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println("Console OUTPUT : \n"+sb.toString());
            process.destroy();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
   }
}
```

*In Eclipse to find [Short cuts](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?nav=%2F1_4):*

Help ► Help Contents ► Java development user guide ► References ► Menus and Actions

Answer (score 4):

I have this folder structure:

> D:\JavaProjects\OlivePressApp\com\lynda\olivepress\Main.class
>   D:\JavaProjects\OlivePressApp\com\lynda\olivepress\press\OlivePress.class
>   D:\JavaProjects\OlivePressApp\com\lynda\olivepress\olives\Kalamata.class
>   D:\JavaProjects\OlivePressApp\com\lynda\olivepress\olives\Ligurian.class
>   D:\JavaProjects\OlivePressApp\com\lynda\olivepress\olives\Olive.class

`Main.class` is in package `com.lynda.olivepress`

There are two other packages:

> com.lynda.olivepress.press
>
> com.lynda.olivepress.olive

1) Create a file named `"Manifest.txt"` with Two Lines, First with Main-Class and a Second Empty Line.

```
Main-Class: com.lynda.olivepress.Main
```

D:\JavaProjects\OlivePressApp\ `Manifest.txt`

2) Create JAR with Manifest and Main-Class Entry Point

D:\JavaProjects\OlivePressApp>`jar cfm OlivePressApp.jar Manifest.txt com/lynda/olivepress/Main.class com/lynda/olivepress/*`

3) Run JAR

`java -jar OlivePressApp.jar`

Note: `com/lynda/olivepress/*` means including the other two packages mentioned above, before point 1)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to deal with those details, you can also use the export jar assistants from Eclipse or NetBeans.

Comment: we did, I moved the jar to another computer and it is not opening :)

Answer (score 1):

- Follow this answer, if you've got a `jar` file, and you need to run it
- See troubleshooting sections for hints to solve most common errors

### Introduction

There are several ways to run java application:

1. `java -jar myjar.jar` - is the default option to run application
2. `java -cp my-class-path my-main-class` or `java -classpath my-class-path my-main-class`
3. `java --module-path my-module-path --module my-module/my-main-class`
4. Deployment to an enterprise server. It's when you have `war` or `ear` file. We'll omit the explanation for this
   case

In this answer I'll explain, how to run a `jar` if you have to run it manually, give hints to resolve common problems.

### `java -jar`

Start with the most common option: run the `jar` file using the `-jar`. Example:

```bash
java -jar myjar.jar
```

If it fails:

- with `no main manifest attribute`, then the `jar` is not executable:

  - If you're trying to build a `jar`
    see [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9689793/6486622)
  - Otherwise, proceed with classpath or module-path solution below
- with other error, then see "Troubleshooting" section below

### Classpath or module path

If `-jar` failed, then the jar should be run using classpath or module-path.

*Module-path is used, when an application is modular itself.*
*JPMS - Java Platform Module System - is a modern way to develop, distribute and run applications. For details:*

1. *Watch excellent [Modular Development with JDK 9 by Alex Buckley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLPPXlhPzHE)*
2. *See [awesome-java-module-system](https://github.com/sormuras/awesome-java-module-system)*

To run a jar:

1. Determine if it's modular or not:

   1. Invoke:

      ```bash
      jar --describe-module --file=path-to-jar-file
      ```
2. Examine output:

   1. If you see `No module descriptor found.` in the **first** line, then proceed with classpath solution below
   2. If you see something similar to:

   ```
   org.diligentsnail.consoleconsumer@1.0-SNAPSHOT jar:file:///home/caco3/IdeaProjects/maven-multi-module-project-demo/jars/console-consumer.jar!/module-info.class
   requires java.base mandated
   requires org.diligensnail.hellolibrary
   ```

   continue with `module-path` solution below

*See also: [List modules in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46616520/6486622)*

### Classpath

Try the following:

```bash
java -cp my-jar.jar my-main-class
```

- `-cp` is the same as `-classpath`
- `my-jar.jar` is the jar to run
- `my-main-class` is name of the class with `static void main(String[])` method

Example:

```bash
java -cp jars/console-consumer.jar org.diligentsnail.consoleconsumer.Main
```

### Module-path

Try the following command:

```bash
java --module-path my-jar.jar --module my-module-name/my-main-class
```

- `my-jar.jar` is the `jar` to run
- `my-module-name` is name of the module where `my-main-class` belongs

  - Usually `my-module-name` is in the `module-info.java` file
- `my-main-class` - the class with the `static void main(String[])` method

If it fails with `FindException`:

- Example of message:

  ```
  Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
  java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.fxml not found, required by org.diligentsnail.javafxconsumer
  ```
- Usually, this means the `my-jar.jar` has a dependency on the other `jar`.
  For example, the application uses a third party library.
  See "Supplying dependencies" below

### Troubleshooting

#### `UnsupportedClassVersionError`

Update java. See [List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9170832/6486622)

#### `NoClassDefFoundError`, `NoSuchMethodError`, `NoSuchFieldError`

See:

1. "Supplying dependencies" section
2. [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413/6486622)

### Supplying dependencies

An `Error` or `Exception` is thrown when an application run with missing or out of date dependencies.
Common exceptions and errors:

1. `NoClassDefFoundError`, `NoSuchFieldError`, `NoSuchMethodError`
2. `ClassNotFoundException`, `NoSuchFieldException`, `NoSuchMethodException`
3. `FindException`

To supply dependencies:

1. Determine the list of dependencies

   1. Usually it's a list of `jar` or can be a list of directories or both
2. Join the list with `:` if you're running Unix, `;` - if you're on Windows
3. Invoke java with `-classpath` or `--module-path`

#### Example

- Project [maven-multimodule-project-demo](https://github.com/diligent-snail/maven-multimodule-project-demo)
- I'm trying to run `console-consumer.jar`:

  - Command:

    ```bash
    java -classpath jars/console-consumer.jar org.diligentsnail.consoleconsumer.Main
    ```
  - `jars/console-consumer.jar` is the `jar` I'm trying to run
  - `org.diligentsnail.consoleconsumer.Main` is the class with main method
- Error I get:

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/diligentsnail/hellolibrary/Hello
    at org.diligentsnail.consoleconsumer.Main.main(Main.java:11)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.diligentsnail.hellolibrary.Hello
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 1 more
  ```
- Missing dependency is `jars/hello-library.jar`
- Correct command:

  ```
  java -classpath jars/console-consumer.jar:jars/hello-library.jar org.diligentsnail.consoleconsumer.Main
  ```

Answer (score -3):

To run jar, first u have to create

> executable jar

then

> java -jar xyz.jar

command will work