# Cannot load drivers for SQL Server on WSO2 Data Services Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am attempting to create a new Data Service in WSO2 Data Services Server to connect with SQL Server 2005. However, every time I test the connection I receive the error message "Driver class com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver can not be loaded".

```
Data Source Type: RDBMS, Non-XA-DataSource
Database Engine: Microsoft SQL Server
Driver: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver 
...
```

I don't believe my connection string or credentials are a problem as it fails on loading the driver.

What is the step that I'm missing in this process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the Microsoft SQL driver jar inside repository/components/lib of DSS distribution in order to load the driver class.

Comment: please add where we get jar file?

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure has changed for Enterprise Integrator v6 you will need to drop off the file into your [EI_HOME]/lib folder. Default folder is "C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.6.0\lib".

Depending on what version of Java you are using, you may download the corresponding version from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#previous-releases).

Extract the file and you drop the jar:

1. mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar - for java 1.8 class version 52

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers) for class versions.