# Unsupported major.minor version 49.0 under tomcat 5

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, java

Receiving this error while trying to run J2EE application under Java 1.4, Tomcat 5.0

Error:

```
**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)**
```

I have compiled the code with Jdk 1.4.2 and java 1.4 under eclipse

i need to run this application under Java 1.4 and Tomcat 5 only, what am i missing here. is some thing wrong with my j2SDK 1.4.2? where can i download a fresh copy of jdk 1.4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-major-version-numbers) - your problem is a class compiled with JDK5 as target version, and that won't run under JDK1.4. Figure out which class/jar and recompile with JDK1.4 and you're good to go.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Move away from Java 1.5 and Tomcat 5.0 **right now**. They are both dead for years. You are leading yourself into trouble.