# Java Major Version Mismatch

Tags: java

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1 with JDK 1.7.03 to develop a Web application.

Then i execute the Build command, to get a .war file.
Next i decompress this war file using Winrar.

Finally i execute javap -verbose on any class that i wrote.

The thing is, im getting Major Version: 50, when i should have Major Version: 51

At least according to [this  Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers).

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your project settings; maybe it has a 1.6 compile target setting?

Comment: Maybe on your pc you have more than one jdk or jre, and the server runs with another java version. Also check the JAVA_HOME env variable.

Comment: I checked my JAVA_HOME (in Windows), and it points to JDK 1.7.03, i checked then mi compile target and it's using java 1.7 besides i'm using java.nio.file package which is only available since Java 1.7.