# Does .class file contains information about compiler version?

Tags: java, compilation, javac, .class-file

I have class file. It is a result of compilation. Can I know the compiler version which was used for creation of this file?

As a result I want to know something like java 1.6.0_45

Answer (score 2):

No. Class file contains only format version which is not directly corresponds to compiler version.

PS: Class files mainly can be found inside jars. Jars often contains manifests. Manifest may contain compiler version.

PPS: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)

Answer (score -1):

<s>Yes, that information is part of class file.</s> More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html).

**Edit:**
I stand corrected. The compiler version is not part of the class file. I confused major and minor versions with compiler version. Still keeping the link since it provides useful information pertaining to the question.

Comment: No it doesnt. If you read you own link you will see that onli class file format version is stored