# How to enforce the correct behavior for the squid:S1161 rule: "@Override" annotation should be used on any method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I develop a Java library which is intended for applications based on **JDK5**. Tools used to build applications require JDK7 or bigger. I use version 8 update 45:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

After the analysis I received a lot of False Positives on methods that are implementing interface specification, e.g:

```
public interface FileScanner {

    Collection<File> getFiles(File directory, String[] includes, String[] excludes);
}
```

[image: False Positive Example]

(see full sources: https://github.com/gabrysbiz/maven-plugin-utils)

I found that rule makes decisions based on bytecode (see [Jira ticket](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-249)). My class major version is equal to 49 which is related to JDK5 (see [major version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9170832/4944847))

```
$ javap -verbose AntFileScanner.class
Classfile /D:/Projects/maven-plugin-utils/sources/plugin-utils/target/classes/biz/gabrys/maven/plugin/util/io/AntFileScanner.class
  Last modified 2015-07-16; size 1881 bytes
  MD5 checksum 7ea340377469b44df88d5936c2ff4134
  Compiled from "AntFileScanner.java"
class biz.gabrys.maven.plugin.util.io.AntFileScanner implements biz.gabrys.maven.plugin.util.io.FileScanner
  minor version: 0
  major version: 49
  flags: ACC_SUPER
```

I run the analysis using [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) 1.619 with [SonarQube Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Jenkins+Plugin) 2.2.1. I use [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) 5.1.1 with [Java Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin) 3.4.

How can I correct it?

Comment: In my opinion this is not a a false positive. An interface in java is nothing more than a special form of a class containing only public abstract methods (since Java 8 even with default implementations). So implementing an interface is a limited form of inheritation (to work around the problems of multiple inheritance), and you in fact override the abstract method.

Comment: You didn't understand the question. I have no problem with inheritance, but with [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) rule.

Comment: I think I did, and I think you perhaps misunderstood the use of @Override annotations.

Comment: Override annotation can be applied only to the methods overriding superclass in **JDK5**. Since Java 6 the Override annotation can be applied to methods that implements the interface ones. This means that I can not add annotations in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Java Plugin 3.9 ([SONARJAVA-818](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-818), see [release notes](https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10973&version=12852)).

Answer (score 2):

Some other people have the same problem, as you can see in the link:

http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/page=91

I tried to solve by using the 'sonar.java.source' and 'sonar.java.target' as suggested:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Features+details

But I think it only works now for the PMD Plugin:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/PMD+Plugin

Then, I saw the JIRA ticket. So, actually there is a bug in this situation. The JIRA CR is closed, but the problem still happens on Java 5:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-249

*"In fact we can't implement this rule right now.
The @Override annotation has source retention and is removed by the compiler.
So our only chance to detect it is from the AST.
But, we can detect if a method actually overrides another one only from the bytecode currently.
So this rule depends on the symbol table being available from checks."*

There is a new unresolved CR to solve this, https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-818.

When fixed, it will use the property 'sonar.java.source' I said before.

So, to solve this while the fix is not ready, we have two options:

1) Mark it as 'false positive' on the server;
2) Use a '@SuppressWarnings' annotation using the rule reference (S1161):

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ

In this case your code would be:

```
public class FileScannerImpl implements FileScanner {
    @SuppressWarnings("squid:S1161")
    Collection<File> getFiles(File directory, String[] includes, String[] excludes) {
         [...]
    }
}
```