# find the compiled class version number

Tags: java, javac

My project consists of some third party jar files, which was compiled in different version of java. 
My project is using older version of java so i am getting `UnsupportedClassVersionError` while executing the application. 
Is there any other way to get the version of `java/jre number[45..51]` in which the class files are compiled so that i can check the jar files before using it.

Comment: You need the version of the class files or the version of your JRE?

Comment: version of java in which class files are compiled!

Comment: You may use asm: http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visit(int, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: I hope it is third party jar. Even i want this version of class files of asm.. compiled. Anyway thanks for the info!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `javap` (with `-v` for verbose mode), and specify any class from the jar file. For example, looking at a Joda Time jar file:

```
javap -cp joda-time-2.7.jar -v org.joda.time.LocalDate
```

Here the `-cp` argument specifies the jar file to be in the classpath, the `-v` specifies that we want more verbose information, and then there's the name of one class in the jar file.

The output starts with:

```
Classfile jar:file:/c:/Users/Jon/Test/joda-time-2.7.jar!/org/joda/time/LocalDate.class
  Last modified 12-Jan-2015; size 16535 bytes
  MD5 checksum d19ebb51bc5eabecbf225945eccd23ef
  Compiled from "LocalDate.java"
public final class org.joda.time.LocalDate extends org.joda.time.base.BaseLocal implements org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,java.io.Serializable
  minor version: 0
  major version: 49
```

The "minor version" and "major version" bits are the ones you're interested in.

It's possible that a single jar file contains classes compiled with different versions, of course.

Comment: To know what version printed there corresponds to what java version, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers

Answer (score 2):

If you only have standard Unix tools available and not the `javap` command then you can get a class file version in the form of a hex `<minor> <major>` version like this:

```
$ dd if=YourFile.class ibs=1 skip=4 count=4 of=/dev/stdout status=none | od -An -tx2 --endian=big
```

Example output. `0034` is `52` and therefore this class is java 8.

```
 0000 0034
```