# Java backward compatibility issue - bytecode for JDK 6 not running in JRE 6

Tags: java

In the computer used for development, I have Java 8 installed. So in order to make my application compatible with older Java versions, I went as far back as possible when compiling the code. But still I get

> Could not find the main class: mypackage.MyClass. Program will exit.

This is my development environment:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode, sharing)
```

in Netbeans, I've compiled the project using

> Project Properties->Sources->Source/Binary Format: JDK 6

and indeed I get:

```
> javap -verbose MyClass | "version"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
```

Major 50 means java 6, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers).

The application runs fine in my development machine. However, when I try to run my jar file in another machine which has

```
> java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)
```

and I get this:

```
> java -jar MyClass.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Could not find the main class: mypackage.MyClass. Program will exit.
```

Shouldn't it run fine if the computer has Java 6 and the compiled byte code also is java 6 compatible?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you intend to use JavaFX? Where do you use/import an `Application` class?

Comment: Yes. It is a JavaFX application. I guess I've found my answer here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to this is probably because Java FX was not bundled into JRE/JDK 6.

I was unable to find the relevant package in the [package overview summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html) as well as 
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX#JavaFX_8) states that

> JavaFX is now part of the JRE/JDK for Java 8 (released on March 18,
>   2014) and has the same numbering, i.e., JavaFX 8.

Comment: Yeap. That's the case. JavaFX libraries come with Java 7 and onwards.