# Unsupported class file major version 55 when executing sonar-maven-plugin under openjdk11

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i looked around the similar issues and replies, but did not find the solution for mine.

I am using openjdk11 and apache-maven-3.5.4 for my project compile and package, everything works fine and the application is running normally.

But on my executing the sonar analysis based on connecting to sonarcube server via maven commands, it failed and some issue happen. This command worked when i was using jdk6 and maven 3.2.1.

The maven command used:
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url={mysonarcube.server} -Dsonar.login={mysonartoken}

The key pom.xml relates to sonar:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0-beta</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The error message as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:242)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:176)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:60)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:109)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:116)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:110)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:93)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:302)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:297)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:271)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

Could anyone help or give me some hint, thanks.

Comment: How is it going? I'm banging my head on this problem right now

Comment: @heldt, i am waiting for the update result of sonarcube server from company. Currently it appears benzonico' answer might be the correct one, since i got same reply from my another loop in sonar community 
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unsupported-class-file-major-version-55-when-executing-sonar-maven-plugin-under-openjdk11/3507

Answer (score 11):

SonarJava analyzer installed on your server is most probably <5.8

To be able to analyze Java 11 binary files you need to upgrade to SonarJava 5.8+ on your sonarqube instance.

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with Java Versions.

You could also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers) about "major versions".

I'm also not sure wether sonarqube already supports java 11.

So if you have a class compiled with java11 and sonarqube wants to check this (but does not support java11 yet) then this might be the problem.