# Unable to execute applet program(applet is not initialized)

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/* <applet code="Demonstration_21" width=300 height=300> </applet> */
public class Demonstration_21 extends Applet{

    public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Welcome",150,150);
    }
}
```

I have written this code to run an applet program but whenever I compile it gives some warning as:

1. Demonstration_21.java uses or overrides a deprecated API
2. Recompile with Xlint:deprecation for details.

And whenever I run this code it gives error as:

```
Demonstration_21 has been compiled by a more recent version of Java
Runtime(class file version 55.0),this version of Java Runtime only 
recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

My appletviewer is not initialized.

Comment: Java Applet is deprecated in Java 9. Unless you are forced to use it for school work or so, better to not waste your time.

Comment: @iTech *"Unless you are forced to use it for school work.."* And if that is the case, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). That was written even **before** applets & JWS were deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You should build it with Java 8 instead of Java 11.

Here is a list of class file versions an the related Java major versions
[List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)

Answer (score -1):

you miss something..

In applet tag code attribute you have to specify .class file.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/* <applet code="Demonstration_21.class" width=300 height=300> </applet> */
public class Demonstration_21 extends Applet{

    public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Welcome",150,150);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"you have to specify .class file"* No, you *don't*. The proper form of the `code` parameter is the fully qualified class name, not the file name and not the path + file name. I've yet to encounter a browser that would *fail* to load an applet due to adding `.class`, but it is both unnecessary & incorrect.

Comment: You don't have to specify the .class file, you just have to compile your project using the JDK 8 because if you use JDK 9+ it won't compile because it has been deprecated on those JDK's.