# How do I get my application to run with Java WebStart

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have been trying to figure this out on and off for a couple of weeks now and today I spent a considerable amount of time with an old professor at UTD and we still were not able to figure it out.

I have an application I've been working on that I would like to deploy as a WebStart application. I have tried doing this Self Signed and Unsigned and get different errors for both.

Right now I'm just trying to get the application to launch locally on my machine (Running latest MacOS).

I have updated my JDK to 11.0.2. Tried different configurations with signed and unsigned certificates. Tried adding the application .jar and .jnlp files to the Site Exception List in Java Console (as well as other random things to see if any error changed, which it didn't.)
Occasionally I would see that activation.jar (for JavaBeans Activation Framework from Oracle)  that I have added as a dependency would come up saying that the application was being blocked because the certificate had expired. But I haven't been able to recreate this in most of the configurations I've been trying recently. I have gone through as many of the even relatively close questions posted on here and none of them have gotten me any closer to a resolution.

JNLP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/MSVO/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>MSVO</title>
    <vendor>Thomas</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>MSVO</description>
    <description kind="short">MSVO</description>
    <icon href="splash_screen.jpg" kind="splash"/>
</information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="11+"/>
    <jar href="MSVO.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.6.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/joda-time-2.10.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/mail.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/smtp-1.4.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
    <extension href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="Controller.MSVO_controller">
</application-desc>
```

For Unsigned I get the following exception:

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Controller/MSVO_controller has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I run it as Self Signed I get:

[image: error]

Let me know if you need any other information and I will gladly update this.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: [Please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers). You compile with Java 11, but try to run with 8. Fix this (depends on what instrument you use, but generally it is not a problem - just configure the compiler to produce code for 8) and then try again

Comment: @igorepst Well, it didn't work, but it did change the error I am receiving. Now it is back to calling out the activation.jar file that I mentioned in my original post. The error window that comes up essentially says - Name: MSVO (my project's name) Location: file:// (it lists no file path, which I'm not sure if this is normal behavior or not) Reason:  The following resource is signed with a weak signature algorithm MD5withRSA and is treated as unsigned: file/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/MSVO/dist/lib/activation.jar...

Comment: @igorepst I tried adding the file name above to the Exception Site List as well as file:/ just to see if it would work and it did not.

Comment: Fine, why not to change the signing algorithm to stronger one?

Comment: @igorepst I wasn't aware that you could change the signing algorithm for a jar file that you didn't create. I'll have to do some research on how to do that. Thank you for the suggestion.