# What is JNI error that is showing in CMD after executing program?

Tags: java

I was studying Annotations in that while executing the below problem.

this code i am executing in JDK 12.0.1 in windows 10.

```
class food{
   public void eat(){
      System.out.println("eat something");
   }
}
class food1 extends food{
   @Override
   public void eat(){
     System.out.println("done...........");
   }
}
class test{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
       food f=new food1();
       f.eat();
    }
}
```

I expected output-done but it is showing error

```
\\Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try 
\\again
\\Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: food 
\\has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class 
\\file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes 
\\class file versions up to 52.0
    \\at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    \\at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    \\at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    \\at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    \\at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    \\at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You have mismatched versions: **food has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 **

Answer (score 0):

According to [List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)  You will know that you mixed Java8 and Java 12 when compiling and running. You need make it consistent by yourself.