# Class file has wrong version xxx, should be xxx

Tags: java, scala, build, sbt

When I try to compile with sbt I get the error

```
cannot acces org.xxx bad class file: C\:Users\xxx class file has wrong version 57.0, should be 55.0 Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

The problem is that I've set in intellij idea project sdk and project language level to java 11. 
Also I've checked with java -version and javac -version and they both say it's java 11.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, I had to delete all target folders from project and recompile. Now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have same problem:

1. Change your java and javac version (you can check it with java --version and javac --version)
2. In intellij file -> project structure -> under project settings: Project 
   Here you can change project sdk
3. Remove all target folders and recompile

Additionally:
Java major versions:

> Java 1.2 uses major version 46
>
> Java 1.3 uses major version 47
>
> Java 1.4 uses major version 48
>
> Java 5 uses major version 49
>
> Java 6 uses major version 50
>
> Java 7 uses major version 51
>
> Java 8 uses major version 52
>
> Java 9 uses major version 53
>
> Java 10 uses major version 54
>
> Java 11 uses major version 55
>
> Java 12 uses major version 56
>
> Java 13 uses major version 57
>
> Java 14 uses major version 58

[List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)