# When i run flutter doctor --android-licenses it shows me this error in VS Code Terminal and CMD; Why?

Tags: android, flutter

i'm getting this *Error* when i run command to get **android license** for **flutter**

```
PS C:\Users\lappy\hello_world> flutter doctor --android-licenses

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: What's your java version?

Comment: setup the environmental variable and run `flutter doctor` again

Comment: @Ashok
java version "1.8.0_25"

Comment: @faysalneowaz it's DONE

Comment: ok great @Mital Rakholiya

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter doctor --android-licenses gives a java error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error)