# google_maps_flutter - Custom Marker Icons: Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

I am using google_maps_flutter and want to use custom marker icons (based on a category, I want to use different icons).

#### CODE

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**pubspec.yaml**
`google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6`

**Maps_view.dart**

```
HashMap bitmaps = new HashMap<String, BitmapDescriptor>();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createBitMaps();
  }

  void _createBitMaps() {
    List<String> cats = categories; // List of categories
    // Based on the category, I want to choose a different asset. The name of the asset and the name of the category are for this reason the same. 
    for (String cat in cats) {
      BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), 'lib/assets/categorie_icons_location/' + cat + '.png').then((onValue) {
          setState(() => bitmaps[cat] = onValue);
        }
      );
    }
  }
...
_markers.add(
                       Marker(
                         markerId: MarkerId('_' + docs[i]['title'] + '_' + docs[i]['latitude'] + '_' + docs[i]['longitude']),
                         position: LatLng(double.parse(docs[i]['latitude']), double.parse(docs[i]['longitude'])),
                         // Use custom icon based on 'category' (from a firebase document) 
                         icon: bitmaps[docs[i]['category']],
                         infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                           title: docs[i]['title'],
                           snippet: docs[i]['street'],
                           onTap: () {}
                         )
                       )
                     );
```

#### ERROR

The following error appears when I start my app:
`Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted`

#### NOTE

As soon as I comment the code with the custom icons, my app runs perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You might have used the wrong Android Manifest.xml. Please check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67121766/11708327

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in my logs.  After some muddling, I got a different error:

`com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap`

I added an assets stanza to pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

And now both errors are fixed.
See [Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

"Muddling" mostly involved the ordering and invocation of the async functions to acquire my marker locations and fromAssetImage(), including await/.then and changing async functions between initState() and Widget Build().  I suspect the execution order affects the actual exceptions invoked.