# Getting this error, when I try to to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in terminal in my Mac m1 air

Tags: flutter, android-studio, air, apple-m1, flutter-android

I tried all solutions in stackoverflow.. None are working .. Please let me know if anyone facing the same issue and have got the solution.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 5 more

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you tried ALL the solutions in Stackoverflow?

I also have a new MacBook Air M1 and installed Flutter without any fuss.
I got the same exception and this question was of great help: [flutter doctor --android-licenses gives a java error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error)

If you have already tried this, please update your question with ALL the solutions that didn't work for you.

Add: Make sure that you have `JAVA_HOME` variable set along with `PATH`. It would also be helpful if you could share the
`flutter doctor` summary.