# Getting error while running flutter doctor tried to uninstall everything but getting this error after installing again again

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

**i am getting errors while running flutter doctor** how can i solve them please help.

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.4)
[!] Android Studio
    X android-studio-dir = \
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

When i am running **flutter doctor --android-licenses** its giving me exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
```

Comment: `flutter doctor --android-licenses` run this command will resolve your issue of X Android license status unknown.

Comment: Android studio is installed on your system?

Comment: for android studio `flutter config --android-sdk="/home/user/Android/Sdk"`

Comment: its not solving but giving an exception Usama Altaf

Comment: what exception?\

Comment: First install android sdk if installed already then go to sdk and install sdk command line tools then run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: added in the description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error

Comment: My problem of Android studio is solved but the lisense one is still there

Comment: did you followed the link that I gave to you

Comment: Thankyou so much my problem is solved now.

Comment: Welcome :) Happy Coding.

Comment: Here the same problem, try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter

Comment: if you have still this issue then follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67898576/8218866