# How do I fix my dart dev tools? (Flutter Android License - Error 65 )

Tags: android, flutter, dart, path

I try to get my dart devtools running but when I want to accept the android liceneses I get the following error:

**$ flutter doctor --android-licenses**

> Fehler: Hauptklasse Straub\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\.. konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden

> Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Straub\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\//

Does somebody have an idea how to fix this?

**Flutter Doctor**

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.4.0-5.0.pre.181, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale de-DE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Are you sure about your path variables? Can you post flutter doctor also?

Comment: Here, same error: [flutter doctor --android-licenses gives a java error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error)

Comment: Posted my flutter doctor above. What should I be sure about my path variables?
I think my User path is fetched wrong? It should be: **Freddy Straub\...** but I can't change my user path can't I?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it.

I had to change my dart devtools cache path to a path without any spaces.

Therefor you have to change the pub environment variables:
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables