# How I can fix Android license status unknown in flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

When I run flutter doctor to check if everything is good I find this problem " Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.", and when I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` previously is show up `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at com.android.repository.api.RemoteListSourceProvider.create(RemoteListSourceProvider.java:51) at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.<init>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:626) at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getRepoConfig(AndroidSdkHandler.java:572) at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:295) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.setSdkHandler(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:101) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:95) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:74) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ... 8 more`

but after I use this command `JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee` ,this what I get
`Error: Could not find or load main class '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions`

How I can fix all of these problems?

NOTE: `Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1` is installed on my android studio

Comment: You can find the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error

Comment: @ace1234 the problem her I couldn't find Android SDK Command-Line Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating your jdk version to the latest and setting jdk path again. also, set JAVA_HOME and make sure build gradle is completed successfuly in android studio. update sdk tools to the latest version and try again.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to work on version 8 only? and when you said "and setting jdk path again" you mean this `JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee` and for JAVA_HOME it should be like this `JAVA_HOME="/home/user/jdk1.8.0_261"` (note I copy this command form another solution)

Comment: by setting jdk path I meant in android studio go to file -> project structure -> sdk location . make sure everything is set correctly. for example my config is like this :   android sdk location: C:\Users\Benyamin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk                      jdk location: 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291