# Flutter unable to find java version on window 10

Tags: java, windows, flutter

In windows 10, flutter doctor shows " unable to find java version".

Java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2 is installed.

What can I do to get this fix?

Comment: Check that the environment properties are set correctly for Java, you can use this link to know how to set those properties, https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

Comment: Is Java on the PATH, is the JAVA_HOME environment variable defined?

Comment: refer to my answer here and also read the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68729690/how-i-can-fix-android-license-status-unknown-in-flutter/68730152#68730152

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.