# When I ran flutter doctor, I got two errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

When I ran flutter doctor, I got two errors.

1 - It says Visual Studio Not Downloaded Although I Downloaded
2 - Can't Accept Android License
When I type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, I see something like this --> [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XURCL.png)

Comment: 1- In your Visual Studio download manager, install the "Desktop Development with C++".  

2- Follow these steps in Android Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64162776/10659482