# UnsupportedClassVersionError while 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' MacOS

Tags: android, flutter, macos, mobile

**System Settings:**

- MacOS Ventura
- Android Studio Electric Eel

**I am installing Flutter on my Intel Mac.**

After Running `flutter doctor`

The outcome is this:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-x64, locale
    en-MX)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

and after running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` the outcome is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider 
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0),
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I installed Java for Mac from this link on January 2023 from [Here](https://www.java.com/en/download/)

**Has someone encountered the same error? How did you fix it?**

Comment: I have just left an answer. Please let me know. I am working with Mac

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I will try to give a more **detailed solution:**

1. Install the latest version of the Java SDK from [this link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac)
2. Pick Java 19 and the `x64 DMG Installer` (this worked for me)
3. Follow the installation instructions.
4. [optional] If necessary, set your `JAVA_HOME` path following [these instructions](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home) (mac)
5. Test the installation by running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: This worked for me, but using `Arm 64 DMG Installer` for a latest Mac with M1 silicon chip.

Comment: This worked for me! Just needed to update from Java 8 to Java 19 on Linux. I used sdkman and it worked just as well: `sdk install java 19.0.2-oracle`

Comment: This https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/120388#issuecomment-1425196389 worked for me

Answer (score 13):

**For Windows**

1. Download and Install latest JDK from [Java SE Development Kit 19.0.2][1]
2. Set a system variable as

   Variable Name: JAVA_HOME

   Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19
3. Add a path variable name as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
4. Now run `flutter doctor`

Hope, it will solve.
[1]: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows

Comment: It works with JDK 17.

Comment: worked with JDK 21 (ie the latest one atm). thanks

Answer (score 6):

While installing the JDK by Oracle download works, best way to make sure that you have the correct version **on MacOS** is to install JDK using Homebrew (If you don't have Homebrew, Installation instructions: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation). Also, keeping it up-to-date is a lot easier this way.

```
brew install openjdk
```

If you have other OpenJDK versions installed, you may need to link this correct one:

```
brew link --force openjdk@19
```

To make it the default for your shell, add the following lines to ~/.zshrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

And then:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

You only need to do this once.

Then rerun: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally from what [Tomas Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253553/13802520) said about installing the lastest SDK, for windows I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163047/13802520) for adding the JAVA_HOME to the path. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I needed to update the JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac).

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to specify what version you upgraded from an to? That will make this answer more valuable in the future, for people experiencing a similar issue, in terms of isolating whether they're experiencing the same problem, or if your solution is still relevant to them.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled. JRE Java runtime environment and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah @Tomas Ward solution is worked For me. But Let me add some more details For the Windows users.

1. As @Tomas says We need to download **Java SE Development Kit
   19.0.2** First of all Click On [This Link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows) To Download Java SE Development Kit 19.0.2.
2. Then Download **x64 Installer** OR **x64 MSI Installer** Then
   Install Java SE Development Kit In Your System.
3. Now You need to Set OR Update This New Java SE Development Kit Path into Your
   JAVA_HOME Path.

And As You Set/Update JAVA_HOME Path Your Error will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a higher version (jdk17) and successfully executed it. But I don't think this is a good idea. Let's wait for the official solution

Comment: Hi, and thanks for joining Stack Overflow. Please do not leave an "Answer" unless it addresses solving the problem. Short messages similar to this one should rather be left as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. So I finally bit the bullet and switched over to asdf. It's worth it and will save you so much trouble in the future.

1. `asdf install java adoptopenjdk-19.0.0+36`
2. `asdf global java adoptopenjdk-19.0.0+36`
3. Do what [this comment](https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java/issues/51#issuecomment-611049565) suggests and add this to your .zshrc

   ```
   # set JAVA_HOME on every change directory
   function asdf_update_java_home {
     asdf current java 2>&1 > /dev/null
     if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]
     then
         export JAVA_HOME=$(asdf where java)
     fi
   }

   precmd() { asdf_update_java_home; }
   # end set JAVA_HOME
   ```
4. `exec zsh` # reloads current terminal to use changed .zshrc
5. `echo $JAVA_HOME` should show asdf directory one
6. `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Machine details

- Macbook Pro M1
- ZSH as my shell