# Error when doing flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm trying to install flutter, but when i put "flutter doctor --android-licenses" in my cmd, i got this error :

```
Erreur : LinkageError lors du chargement de la classe principale com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I saw many answer about this, saying that we should just update java, and I did.

Here is my env variables :

[image: env variables]
[image: env variable]

Any idea ?

edit : I  tried to reinstall sdk but stil not work

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Java 11 instead of 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Installing Android SDK Command-line tools from Android SDK Manager may solve this problem. You can also have a look here for help. I hope it gets resolved.
[flutter doctor --android-licenses gives a java error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error)