# Gradle Test fails because of UnsupportedClassVersionError when I build a Docker image - locally it works fine

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, gradle

I have an issue with the `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` error that is being thrown during my test executions. I understand the error and solved it before but in this case I am a bit lost.

This is the error messages (does appear for all test classes):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/game/backend/resolver/QueryResolverTest has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

And this is my *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM gradle:6.6.1-jdk8 as builder
USER root
WORKDIR /builder
ADD . /builder
RUN gradle build --debug

FROM openjdk:11.0.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8082
COPY --from=builder /builder/build/libs/game-backend.jar app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

What I don't understand here is why he says it's `compiled by a more recent version`?
The `FROM gradle:6.6.1-jdk8` tells me it's JDK 1.8 which means it's class file version **52** (according to: [List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)). So why is it saying the class was compiled by **55** (Java 11) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I acted a bit small minded here. Even tho the docker image `FROM gradle:6.6.1-jdk8` is in fact JDK 1.8 does not mean that gradle will compile with JDK 1.8 it seems.

So I changed it to `FROM gradle:6.6.1-jdk11 as builder` using JDK 11 now. Why is that helping now?

Well my `build.gradle.kt` is using:

```
...
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
...
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
...
```

Which obviously shows that gradle will **compile** my classes with JDK 11. However what I thought is that only the JDK given by the Docker image `FROM` (that was JDK8) is available and `gradle` should've tell me something like

> You wanted to build with JDK 11, since that's what your build.gradle says but you only have JDK 8 available (through the gradle:6.6.1-jdk8) image.

But I forgot that `gradle` itself can download stuff. Which is logical since it's downloading dependencies. So it also seems to download the JDK (11 in this case) it needs to compile according to the `build.gradle`. However **Running** the tests is using the **Java Runtime Environment** and that was brought in by `gradle:6.6.1-jdk8` therefore the JRE 8 and not 11 (which is needed since it's all compiled for 11 by `gradle`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two `FROM` commands in your Dockerfile and the Java 11 is second so is probably taking precedence.

Comment: No because the gradle build is running under the layer of the first. The second `FROM` is therefore never reached