# JavaFX application fail to launch with native exe bundle created with intellij ide

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I have build a JavaFX application which can be executed by its jar file. However if i try to run it using the native exe bundle i am receiving two popups:

Error Invoking method

Failed to launch JVM

and the application fails to start.

The Javafx application is build with intellij ide.

The project structure looks as follows;

[image]

when launching the application following popup shows..
[image]

[image]

The config file looks as follows:-
[image]

The packaged jar file is executing properly...
the problem occurs when starting application with launching exe file.
kindly tell me what could went wrong?

UPDATE:
It seems that the build output runtime/bin directory does not contain java.exe file therefore i think the application does not launches.
the output when try to run the application is as follows:

[image]

i have build the application with intellij idea, i think there is a problem with that. Kindly look into this matter.

UPDATED:-

[image]

Comment: Check again your options under the Artifact Configuration -> Java FX tab, including **Native bundle:** type. Make also sure to try launching it with the 1.8 JDK (add it as a  JAVA_HOME location).

Comment: sir i am using jdk15

Answer (score 0):

Run it from the command line using the runtime that was bundled for you:

If you made an executable Jar (with a proper manifest specifying the classpath and main class)

```
cd firecap
runtime\bin\java -jar app\libs\your-main.jar
```

If you don't have an executable jar use something like

```
cd firecap
runtime\bin\java -cp app\libs\*.* your.main.class.name
```

Since java.exe is a console program you should be able to see the full error output to get a better idea of what is going wrong.

You very likely have missed including a needed module in the runtime.

It is also possible you ran into a bug that I discovered recently: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254920

I created my runtime image with this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJDK-15-Full\bin\jlink.exe"  --no-header-files --no-man-page, --compress=1 --add-modules java.management,java.logging,javafx.controls,java.xml,java.desktop --output C:\MyProject\build\image\runtime
```

But yours may be different depending on what modules you need.  Note also that I used a JDK from BellSoft that included the JavaFX modules to make it easier.

Comment: As you said i have run the application and it is not working and when i checked the bin directory there is no java.exe  application file. i think the application is crashing because of that. I think the intellij idea did not build the application properly. how can i overcome this problem.

Comment: There doesn't have to be a java.exe in the runtime\bin folder.  If jpackage is used, it's launcher exe is used and java.exe isn't required.  If you have access to the jpackage options add --win-console so you can easily see the error messages.

Comment: Is there a build log you could share, or specific configuration options?  I don't use Intellij Idea (I find it requires too much configuration to make it work well), so I don't know specifically what it is trying to do.  If you had a Gradle build file or something like that it would be helpful.

Comment: sir can you provide me with some links so that i can use gradle to build and deploy javafx.

Comment: i have tried everything from openjfx but not working because i have a little knowledge about gradle.

Comment: i have multiple jdk's installed i am not able to set jdk 15 for gradle.

Comment: Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your JDK 15 directory and Gradle will use it for the builds.  You could start by running jlink and jpackage manually after creating your application jar and folder of dependency jars.  Read Gradle docs for the application plugin to get started with that.

Comment: i am getting - Task :app:prepareModulesDir FAILED and  Unsupported class file major version 59

Comment: Please help me in creating the runtime.

Comment: @RanjitVamadevan so you are running your program on an older version of the JRE than what you compiled with and the class file format has changed between those versions.

Comment: my toolchain is java15

Comment: sir i have added updated screenshot   https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vIrV.png

Comment: @RanjitVamadevan I've edited the answer to include an example of running jlink to create a JRE image.

Comment: @RanjitVamadevan You must be running with JRE 14 or earlier to get that error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers

Comment: When creating image with jlink with gradle i am getting exception. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareModulesDir'. > Unsupported class file major version 59

Comment: "Unsupported class file major version 59"  You are mixing different versions of Java, or using tools that don't support the version you are using. Your classes are compiled with a newer version of Java than the tool that generated that error can handle.  Use the latest Gradle and make sure you aren't mixing JDK versions.