# Can't start gluonfx: build

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I can not start gluonfx: build when I want to add my project to the apk, that is, for android

This is error

```
    C:\Users\elkha\.jdks\adopt-openjdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\elkha\OneDrive\Chat\WeatherApp "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=56557:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2021.1.2 com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build -P android
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.gluonapplication:weatherapp >-------------------
[INFO] Building >WeatherApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) @ weatherapp ---
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.gluonapplication:weatherapp >-------------------
[INFO] Building >WeatherApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:compile (default-cli) > process-classes @ weatherapp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ weatherapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ weatherapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:compile (default-cli) < process-classes @ weatherapp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:compile (default-cli) @ weatherapp ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.gluonhq.NativeCompileMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.gluonhq.NativeCompileMojo not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/gluonhq/NativeCompileMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf (ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.355 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-15T17:58:16+05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:compile (default-cli) on project weatherapp: Execution default-cli of goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:compile failed: Unable to load the mojo 'compile' in the plugin 'com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com/gluonhq/NativeCompileMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/1.0.0/gluonfx-maven-plugin-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/gluonhq/substrate/0.0.40/substrate-0.0.40.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/plist/dd-plist/1.22/dd-plist-1.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.49/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.49/bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.11/plexus-java-0.9.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0-beta/asm-7.0-beta.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.25/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.6.0/maven-builder-support-3.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-util/1.3.1/maven-resolver-util-1.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.1/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/25.1-android/guava-25.1-android.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-compat-qual/2.0.0/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.3/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.2/maven-invoker-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.2.v20150114/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-http/1.1.0/aether-transport-http-1.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5/httpclient-4.3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-file/1.1.0/aether-transport-file-1.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/elkha/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-connector-basic/1.1.0/aether-connector-basic-1.1.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.461 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-15T16:58:17+04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) on project weatherapp: Error, gluonfx:build failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gluonapplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>weatherapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>>WeatherApp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.11</attach.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>0.1.42</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.gluonapplication.WeatherMain</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.42</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>21.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>native-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <imageName>example</imageName>
                    <buildArgs>
                        --no-fallback
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.gluonapplication.views.PrimaryPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.gluonapplication.views.SecondaryPresenter</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>host</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                    <version>20190722</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>display</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Help please.I tried many options and couldn't fix it in any way
I still did everything that was said in the documentation gluon, but nothing worked.

Gluon Java Javafx Maven Please Helppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp

Comment: I'm not an android developer, so I don't know the details of this, but the issue appears to be that you're trying to build this with a Java 8 compiler, and some of the library classes you're using have been built with a later version (Java 11?). You probably just need to build/run with later JDK versions.

Comment: i am using 14 java

Comment: The stack trace pretty clearly states "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/gluonhq/NativeCompileMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0". [Class file version 52 corresponds to Java 8.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)

Comment: Yes, that’s the case: you are running Java 8. Actually, IntelliJ’s Maven is set to Java 8. It is better to use an external Maven. Also you are on Windows, and to build for Android you need Linux. See docs at https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android

Comment: I do not know why this is so, but everywhere in the project settings and maven I looked the version of Java is higher than 11

Comment: In the documentation, gluon says that it is possible for Windows too

Comment: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_create_install_an_android_native_image

Comment: As I said, the docs do mention that you need Linux (or WSL2 on Windows or GitHub actions)

Comment: but when i run gluonfx:package throws such an error: Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.0:package (default-cli) on project weatherapp: Error