# Zeppelin issue : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I hope you are doing well.

I am a new user of Apache Zeppelin and I am facing an error (java I think, but not sure) when I run a cross-validation for the random forest with Apache Spark :

```
val rfcv = new CrossValidator()
                        .setEstimator(rf)
                        .setEvaluator(evaluator)
                        .setNumFolds(10)
                        .setEstimatorParamMaps(rfparamGrid)

val rfcvModel = rfcv.fit(trainingData)
```

Here is the error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
  at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$6.apply(CrossValidator.scala:166)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$6.apply(CrossValidator.scala:166)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4.apply(CrossValidator.scala:166)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4.apply(CrossValidator.scala:146)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(CrossValidator.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(CrossValidator.scala:122)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$$anonfun$11.apply(Instrumentation.scala:185)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:185)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator.fit(CrossValidator.scala:122)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1409)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1382)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.DecisionTreeMetadata$.buildMetadata(DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.run(RandomForest.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor$$anonfun$train$1.apply(RandomForestRegressor.scala:133)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor$$anonfun$train$1.apply(RandomForestRegressor.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$$anonfun$11.apply(Instrumentation.scala:185)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:185)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor.train(RandomForestRegressor.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor.train(RandomForestRegressor.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator.fit(Estimator.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcD$sp(CrossValidator.scala:154)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CrossValidator.scala:153)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CrossValidator.scala:153)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
  at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
  at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:494)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$5.apply(CrossValidator.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$5.apply(CrossValidator.scala:152)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1$$anonfun$4.apply(CrossValidator.scala:152)
  ... 61 more
```

I am using Linux Mint 18 and I was using Jupyter Notebook for big data analysis with Apache Spark using the spylon-kernel and I had not this error.

Thank you very much for you help and have a nice day!

Jean

Comment: you have Java 8, but there is a library compiled for Java 11: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers

Comment: Major 55 corresponds to Java 11, do do you think that only Java 11 is supported ? Thanks à lot for your answer !

Comment: FWIW - Your error comes from the JVM (and possibly Java code), but the code you are showing is Scala.

Comment: That’s really happens when you run code compiled for Java 11 on Java 8

Comment: @ Alex Ott : I have Java 11 installed (if there are no mistakes...), when I run :

**$ echo $JAVA_HOME**
, I get :
**/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64**

How can I do ? Thanks !