# Error about loading the ‘FSelector’ package

Tags: r, fselector

what does the below error mean?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘FSelector’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWeka', details:
  call: new_Weka_package_manager()
  error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: weka/core/WekaPackageManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Comment: 52.0 corresponds to Java 8 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)). Are you running an even older version?

Comment: It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes the code leading up to this error. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). That being said, if you received this error after attempting to install this package, you do not have the dependencies installed. The `FSelector` package depends on two other packages: `RWekajars` and `RWeka`. Typically dependencies install automatically. You can install them separately, though.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.