# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Docker Compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I have a microservice that is called account.query. When I try to up services by using docker compose up command, **account.query** is getting an error.

- I have also a microservice that is called **account.cmd**, but **it is not getting** an error.

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours, but I could not.

Here is **Docker file** my **account.query microservice**.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11.0.4_11-jre-hotspot
EXPOSE 5003

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY build/libs/account.query-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx32m"
CMD exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar account.query-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is **Docker logs** for the service.

[image]

Here is my github repository.
https://github.com/dogaanismail/bank-solution

I would be very happy if someone could help.

Comment: That error message often means the jar file was built with a newer JDK than you're running it with; how did you build the jar file?  The screen shot you've attached isn't that easy to read, is it possible to replace it with the text of the error message you get?

Comment: Adding to David's comment: The screenshot says "class file version 61.0". If you look that up (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)), you will see that the classes were apparently compiled for Java 17, but your image is using Java 11.