# Server Tomcat v10.0 Server at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I'm developing a web application in eclipse with Jax-rs framework and I run it on a TomEE plus server. The reason why I use TomEE Plus instead of standard tomcat is that I want to write my app with jax-rs and jax-rs is not supported by the standard tomcat and it will result in 404 every time the app is run. I have downloaded TomEE-Plus-9.0.0-M7 and added it to eclipse by setting the type as Tomcat v10.0 Server and set the installation directory to where i had unzipped the downloaded TomEE Plus files.i have also placed all needed jars for my app in web-inf/lib directory.the problem is that when i try to run the app on the created server i receive this error:

> Server Tomcat v10.0 Server at localhost failed to start

Looking at the console I saw that there are some exceptions being thrown. this is the console :

```
May 20, 2022 5:10:00 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.4
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Server built:          Mar 5 2021 11:07:15 UTC
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Server version number: 10.0.4.0
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: JVM Version:           16+36-2231
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7\wtpwebapps
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
May 20, 2022 5:10:01 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;D:\matlab\runtime\win64;D:\matlab\bin;D:\matlab\polyspace\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\maxplus2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16;\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
May 20, 2022 5:10:02 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Startup: Fri May 20 17:10:03 IRDT 2022
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Copyright 1999-2021 (C) Apache TomEE Project, All Rights Reserved.
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Version: 9.0.0-M7
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build date: 20210503
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build time: 02:36
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.home = D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.base = D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@47f9738
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Succeeded in installing singleton service
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory init
INFO: TomEE configuration file is 'D:\apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M7\conf\tomee.xml'
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
May 20, 2022 5:10:03 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO:   ** Bound Services **
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager printRow
INFO:   NAME                 IP              PORT  
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: -------
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: Ready!
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Server initialization in [4366] milliseconds
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener bindResource
INFO: Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.4]
May 20, 2022 5:10:04 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /Form
May 20, 2022 5:10:05 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Form]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:880)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Form]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Form: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2392)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1227)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1160)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5031)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Form: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2390)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
    ... 42 more

May 20, 2022 5:10:05 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:880)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Form]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Form]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Form: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2392)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1227)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1160)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5031)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Form: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2390)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
    ... 42 more

May 20, 2022 5:10:05 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:880)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Form]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Form]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Form: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2392)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1227)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1160)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5031)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Form: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2390)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for api.AppTest
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
    ... 42 more

May 20, 2022 5:10:05 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
May 20, 2022 5:10:05 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
May 20, 2022 5:10:05 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager stop
INFO: Stopping server services
May 20, 2022 5:10:05 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
```

I have read many solutions including deleting .snap file, deleting the server and creating new one, removing the server from targeted runtimes and ... . i really have no idea what the problem is and it's been two days that i'm stuck on this. I appreciate anyone who can help. thanks in advance.

Comment: jax-rs is perfectly fine on regular tomcat, just include the proper jars in your application and deploy. The error you get is indicating that you have compiled with a higher version of Java then supported by TomEE (or which you use running TomEE). However as stated you don't need TomEE to build a Jax-RS Webservice.

Comment: @M.Deinum Then could you please explain why I get 404 response message for an existing jax-rs resource when I run it on a regular tomcat server?by the way,i'm using jdk-16 and the tomee that I have downloaded supports java 8 or higher.are you sure that the error is related to java version?

Comment: Yes it is related to the java version. You get the error because you are deploying on Tomcat 10 and probably written the application using Java Servlet API and not the Jakarta Servlet API (tomcat 10 is the latter, Tomcat 9 the former).

Comment: It is about the Java version, not JavaEE vs JakartaEE.

Comment: @M.Deinum I haven't used any servlet. I have extended the application class and using jakarta packages instead of javax. and when I assign it's directory to the selected server type it says that the directory contains files of tomcat version 10.0.4 so it can't be assigned to tomcat 9.

Comment: Then add the proper Jax-RS jars to your application (so that they are included) and deploy to tomcat. TomEE is using an old ASM version that doesn't support the java version you are using. ASM7 supports upto Java11, anything higher will fail.

Comment: ok i have already added the jaxrs jars to my project.then what about the 404 message when I use the regular tomcat?could you please check out these two links?see the beginning of this [link](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Step-by-step-RESTful-web-service-example-in-Java-using-Eclipse) and the end of this [link](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Use-Tomcat-Eclipse-to-create-a-JAX-RS-REST-web-service)

Comment: @M.Deinum i forgot to mention you in previous comment

Comment: You need to add the jax-rs api and an implementation, without an implementation it will do nothing. I would also suggest to find another tutorial and if you do follow the tutorial (using the same versions etc. etc.) but you choose to use newer versions. As mentioned add next to the jax-rs api an implementation (like Jersey) and deploy on tomcat instead. The tutorial you link to even says so (not mentioning a concrete implementation, but still referencing that you need an implementation).,

Comment: @M.Deinum hi again, I'm really sorry that I'm leaving another comment after days, I didn't have access to the internet for some days. I did as you said, added the resteasy implementation libraries to the web-inf->lib folder and used the standard tomcat v.10. the problems that I spoke of in this question are gone but when I run the app on the created server (tomcat 10) it doesn't recognize my project and returns 404 for the root address (http://localhost:9999/Form, form is the name of my project).what should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see this in the logs: Unsupported class file major version 60

Is it possible you compiled the code using Java 16 but are now trying to execute on something below?

See also

- [List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2

Comment: Given the error occurs in `org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader`, it seems more likely something is using an old version of ASM to read/modify bytecode, and that version doesn't support class version 60.

Comment: Ah, so the limitation is not from the JVM. Still there are newer classes than what the runtime (including ASM) can digest.

Comment: if I understood you right, you're saying that my code is compiled with java 16 and is executed by a lower version? I didn't have such a problem before. I have written some apps and ran them with a tomcat server before and it would execute correctly but since i deleted that server and added tomEE plus i'm getting this error.

Comment: in window->prefrences->java->compiler it says 16.

Comment: Try to use a previous version, or at least compile code such that it is compatible with previous versions. Not sure how much you'd have to go back in time.