# Is Google Closure Compiler Still Running Online?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Google’s Closure Compiler, which I’ve used for many years, seems to be down (**https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home**).

Googling turned up a lot of conflicting data, some of which seems to imply it’s no longer available online, and you have to run it locally. However, none of the download links I tried worked.

Anyone know the current status of the Google Closure Compiler?

Comment: It's back online now, but the service is deprecated (the project itself is not), so if you depend on it you might want to self-host. If you look up "closure compiler online" in your favorite search engine you'll find a few alternative hosted services, usually ad-supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information is available in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler). Indeed both the [UI](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui) and the [API](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api) are deprecated. You should download the Java application for local use.

See [Getting Started with the Closure Compiler Application](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app):

> Download the most recently released JAR file from the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.javascript/closure-compiler), and save it in closure-compiler.

Now the Maven web UI is indeed far from obvious, but here's how it goes:

1. In the big table, under the **Version** heading, click the version you want. At the time of writing, that's `v20220803`, released on 9 August. (That also answers your question about the current status; new releases are still happening.)
2. In the table at the top, next to **Files**, click the link named "jar" to start your download.

Comment: Downloaded latest jar, but when I ran it, I got this error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

But when I run java -version, it makes no mention of class file versions, only the overall version of the JRE:

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode, sharing)

How do I get the correct class version?

Comment: Upgrade you Java 8 to [at least version 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers).

Comment: Yup, right you are. Until I saw your note, I didn’t know there was a Java version past 8, which is what I got from Oracle last time an auto-update occurred. Looks like the the JDK and accompanying JRE are many versions beyond the consumer JRE, which is evidently still at 8.

Comment: I think it's because of license changes: "Java 8 LTS last free software public update for commercial use was released by Oracle in March 2022, while Oracle continues to release no-cost public Java 8 updates for development[3] and personal use indefinitely." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history Since they don't know if you're using it commercially, it won't auto-update to a version where that is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It's down for me since this morning also. Nothing on their @googledevs Twitter account and no status updates that I can locate