# Java Docker build agent finds java 8 even though it is not installed

Tags: docker, jenkins, jvm, jenkins-agent

## Background

I have a Jenkins server on Ubuntu 18.04 running Java version 11, checked by visiting */manage/systemInfo*

> java.specification.version 11

I have implemented [docker build agents](https://github.com/JoSSte/php-docker-build-slave) based on Ubuntu 22.04 where I have specified that the java version should be 11:

```ini
# install java for Jenkins
RUN apt-get install -qy openjdk-11-jdk
```

I was wondering that all the build nodes stood as offline, and  reading the log saw this:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/remoting/Launcher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

This question references [List of Java class file format major version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers) the Class versions:
52 is java 8
55 is java 11

and sure enough, a little further back in the log:

> [11/14/22 18:35:38] [SSH] Checking java version of java
> [11/14/22 18:35:38] [SSH] java -version returned 1.8.0_312.

so I went hunting for the culprit:

## Attempts to find the culprit

`sudo docker container exec 20e1bfe2b182  ls -l /usr/bin/java` returned

> /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

`sudo docker container exec 20e1bfe2b182  ls -l /etc/alternatives/java` returned

> /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

and even injected `RUN java -version` into my Dockerfile before the line installing opendjk (which indicated no java was installed...)

On the host I have run `apt list --installed |grep jdk`

> openjdk-11-jdk/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.17+8-1ubuntu2~18.04 amd64 [installed]
> openjdk-11-jdk-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.17+8-1ubuntu2~18.04 amd64 [installed]
> openjdk-11-jre/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.17+8-1ubuntu2~18.04 amd64 [installed]
> openjdk-11-jre-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.17+8-1ubuntu2~18.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]

... the same command on the docker image gave similar results...
`find -name java* 2>/dev/null` run from `/` did not give anything useful either

### `which java` output

#### HOST:

> $ which java
> /usr/bin/java
> $ ls -l /usr/bin/java
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov 24  2018 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
> $ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jan 25  2022 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

#### docker

> $ sudo docker compose run man which java
> /usr/bin/java
> $ sudo docker compose run man ls -l /usr/bin/java
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov 14 20:28 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
> $ sudo docker compose run man ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Nov 14 20:28 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

### `echo $PATH` output

#### HOST

> $  echo $PATH
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

#### docker

> $ sudo docker compose run man echo $PATH
> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

### Potential workaround

Adding this to my Dockerfile seems to almost solve the issue:

```ini
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/ /home/jenkins/jdk
RUN chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins/jdk
```

## Question

... so where does the JDK version 8 come from?

Comment: Since [2.361.1, 2022-09-07](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.361.1), Jenkins requires Java 11 (55) to run controller and agentsR. Run `which java` to determine which is really being picked up and `echo $PATH` to understand why getting 8.

Comment: I actually tried `which java`  first - and that only showed openjdk11 - I also tried echo $PATH to no avail either

Comment: Post the outputs of those commands.

Comment: @JoSSte were u able to solve this issue ?? I am also facing the same issue and will be thankful if you can suggest a way

Comment: @Karan I did. you can see the definition of my build slave here: https://github.com/JoSSte/jenkins-build-slave-php/blob/master/Dockerfile As I recall it `FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:jdk11 as agent` was the key

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoSSte for sharing the solution. will check this approach also. currently, I was able to solve the same by some hack which I share in the answer below. the culprit was that it was having 2 JDK versions and it was picking always Java for  8 for some reasons

Answer (score 1):

i wasted 2 days in this and what i found was that my docker container which was running had Two JDK installed ( 1 was default centOS7 and the other was which i am adding in Dockerfile ). This was causing compatibility issues as DOCKER on my Host was running on JDK11 and the docker container( as a slave ) was picking the JDK8 as both Runtime environment was available there.

you can create and add a script inside your docker file to always select runtime of JDK11

```
RUN echo 2 | alternatives --config java
```