# Get java class version from javac or JRE without a compiled class

Tags: java, javac, unsupported-class-version

Java class version can be obtained from a class binary using `javap`

```
javap -verbose Test | grep 'minor\|major'
  minor version: 0
  major version: 55
```

Is it possible to know in advance which class version a JDK will produce?
`java -version` does not show it

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18
```

Usually related to [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi).

Comment: You can also just refer to [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found it interesting to know it from command line for scripting/troubleshooting purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java class major/minor version produced by a JDK can be obtained from `java`, `javac` or `javap` commands as follows

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep -E -e 'java\.(class\.)?version '
javac -J-XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep -E -e 'java\.(class\.)?version '

# testing all 3 commands
for cmd in "java " "javac -J" "javap -J"; do echo "${cmd% *}"; ${cmd}-XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1  | grep -E -e 'java\.(class\.)?version ' ; done
```

Result:

```
java 
    java.class.version = 61.0
    java.version = 17.0.8.1
javac
    java.class.version = 55.0
    java.version = 11.0.20.1
javap
    java.class.version = 55.0
    java.version = 11.0.20.1
```

**Note**: As in my case :p , a Linux misconfiguration could give different results from `java` and `javac` showing that both commands belong to different versions. Than can be usually fixed using `alternatives` command.