# class file has wrong version 62.0, should be 57.0 - While building Jar

Tags: java, jar

I have downloaded Java code from GitHub and am trying to configure or build my changes into a Java package. But I'm getting the below error. I'm not sure what version of Java I need to use to build this project. Any pointers or suggestions would be really helpful.

```
error: cannot access Copier
import com.example.records.core.Copier;
                                    ^
  bad class file: /home/user957/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.example.streaming/streaming-core/v1.36.1/758f1477d776e3273c5397d2d5d7e19b5fa46326/streaming-core-v1.36.1-sdk.jar(/com/example/records/core/Copier.class)
    class file has wrong version 62.0, should be 57.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

mySystem JDK version

```
java -version
openjdk version &quot;18.0.2.1&quot; 2022-08-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-18.0.2.1+1 (build 18.0.2.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-18.0.2.1+1 (build 18.0.2.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: The expected class file version (57.0) hints at Java 13, the path in the error message hints at using Gradle. Does your `build.gradle` contain a statement like `languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(13)`?

Comment: @ThomasKläger java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11  // it uses Java 11
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

Comment: At least one of your dependencies (com.example.streaming:streaming-core:v1.36.1) has been compiled for Java 18 (class file version 62). You will need to find a version of that dependency that is compiled for the Java version that your project uses.

Comment: @ThomasKläger issue has been resolved bu configuring java 18 and  setting gradle java 18 version, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try JDK version 1.9 or higher.
If class files has version 62.0,then least JDK 9 installed on system to be able to compile them

Comment: just because jdk9 is installed, doesn't mean it's used in the compilation process

Comment: BTW Java 9 (1.9) is major 53 - required is 62, that is, Java 18 (not to be confused with 8 or 1.8)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, by just reinstalling my JDK. If you're using IntelliJ, just head to the project settings and click download in the JDK dropdown menu.

I also solved this problem on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine by running `sudo apt install openjdk-13-jdk`, which installs the jdk and
`sudo update-alternatives --config java`, which updates the index of the newest jdk (i think).

If I understood you wrongly with the version needed, just adjust the number behind `openjdk-` to whatever version you need.

[All versions to their corresponding class file versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)