# libGDX cannot successfully generate project for java project

Tags: java, lib

```
* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users / richard / Desktop/Eclipse_WorkSpace/settings.
gradle' (/Users / richard / gradle/ caches / 7.5.1/scripts /dn611r5pg3bcsc902xue6326v).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63
```

I also try deleting the error file and rebuild itself but it still doesn't work

Comment: Your `java` version not compatible to project gradle file I guess.

Comment: From [List of Java class file format major version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers) 63 is for Java 19 and according to [Gradle Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) the 19th is supported from Gradle 7.6, but your version is 7.5.1

Comment: Be aware that you will get warnings (and potential runtime issues) about unsupported JNI if you use Java 19 with libGDX 1.11.