# Dependency Issue in Pac4j Library while upgrading to another one because of bug

Tags: java, saml-2.0, pac4j

My application is compatible with Java8 so I am using the below lib but the below one has a bug according to [AssertionConsumerIndex-Issue](https://groups.google.com/g/pac4j-users/c/1Lxn5lq4SVk/m/hFdwKDS2AAAJ) which is resolved in the v5.1.4 version but when I am upgrading faced issue.

What show I have to do?

```
pluginLibsCompile 'org.pac4j:jee-pac4j:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
pluginLibsCompile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:4.1.0'

pluginLibsCompile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-http:4.1.0'
pluginLibsCompile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-ldap:4.1.0'
pluginLibsCompile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-jwt:4.1.0'

Upgraded to this
pluginLibsCompile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-saml:5.1.5'
```

I am getting an error

`bad class file: /home/rohit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.pac4j/pac4j-core/5.1.5/aa60f665ef03852ce6c92a3cc26caf797640d60b/pac4j-core-5.1.5.jar(org/pac4j/core/context/JEEContext.class) class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0 Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.`

Comment: First I doubt it is wise to mix versions of a framework/libraryu. o mixing 5.0.1, 4.1.0 and 5.1.5 (or higher) is wise, I suspect they should match. That being said, class version 55 is java 11 so it seems that that version of the library isn't usable with Java8 and has a minimum requirement on Java11. Which according to the pac4j website is right. 5.x is Java11, 4.x is Java8 and 6.x is Java 17.

Comment: @M.Deinum why not put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The error you get indicates that the classes you are using are compiled with Java 11. [`class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers) the answer has a list with a lot of Java versions and class file version and a link to the source of this.

If you check the [Pac4J Documentation](https://www.pac4j.org/docs/alldocs.html) this would have been pretty clear as the documentation states that

- Version 4.x is Java 8
- Version 5.x is Java 11
- Version 6.x is Java 17

So either you cannot use version 5.1 and stick with the latest in the 4.x branch or you would need to upgrade to a newer Java version as well. Which I would recommend as Java 8 is getting a bit dated.

In addition I doubt it is wise to mix versions of a framework/library that is in use, as that will certainly lead to incompatibility issues. Your current project appears to be mixing 4.1.0, 5.0.1 and 5.1.5, the versions should all align.

Comment: I can't able to stick to 4.x branch because of an bug  AssertionConsumerIndex-Issue which is fixed in 5.1.4 ,

In that case what Should I have to do: 
- Just because of this we can't shift java-version of our commerce application from java 8 to 11

, Is there any other thing I would can do that ?

Comment: No, you either stick with the version you can use 4.x or upgrade java. Those are your options (as explained).