# Java version issue: gradlew build shadowJar: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63, (using compatible versions)

Tags: java, gradle, shadowjar

```
> ./gradlew --version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.18

//inside build.gradle
dependencies {
...
classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.1.0"
...
}
```

According to the compatibility table here: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow, gradle 6.1.1 with shadow 6.1.0 and Java 11 should be compatible.  However when I try to build using `./gradlew build shadowJar` I get an error about:

```
2023-08-03T14:54:20.719-0700 [ERROR] [com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction] ex
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
```

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers), version 63 is Java 19.  Both `./gradlew` and `java --version` are telling me I'm using 11.0.18 so where does this error about major version 63 come from?

Comment: What about `javac --version`?

Comment: `javac --version` is 11.0.18, same as the others

Comment: Are any of the dependencies that you're trying to fat jar compiled with Java 19?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, the list of dependencies is quite large, how would I check that?  Even if that was the case, shadow 6.1.0 says it should work with 8+

Comment: Let me think. What OS are you using?

Comment: This is on macOS

Comment: My theory could be wrong but I knocked up an app to test jars for their class version. Shall post link in a minute or two. [Here we are](https://technojeeves.com/tech/util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar). Just point that at a directory or jar or class file. `java -jar util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar x.jar`. Is in any case interesting to know what versions you're dealing with

Comment: I think this is potentially a gradle issue, from the gradle 7.6.1 notes:

`- Added support for Java 19.`

Comment: Well you said that there's nothing at 19 present, so it shouldn't *need* to support it

Comment: I was trying a few different combinations of dependency versions and one of my dependencies is solr.  With solr 9.3 I'm getting these issues but it's working for solr 8.x.  Unfortunately, I do specifically need solr 9.x.

Comment: If you point that app at the Solr directory it will find all the jars and tell you what version they've been compiled to

Comment: According to my app, Solr 9.3 is Java 11

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem recently. For me the culprit was Jackson version 2.15.1.
Switching down to 2.14.2 solves the problem.

solr seems to use jackson version 2.15.2 (https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/de234cb9a30d28dd46f3c1eb96732a0bd0f08b8d/versions.props#L8C1-L8C41) so you might want to exclude from shadow and use lower version instead.