# run an .jar file

Tags: java, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to run a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

I have a problem that is driving me crazy for a while:
1 week ago I downloaded this file :" **droidAtScreen-1.0.1.jar**" I could doubleclick it and I could "see" the screen of my android device, the problem is, that on Friday a co-worker change the system Variables to make some stuffs with eclipse, now my jar file hat no icon and i dont know how to run it to capture my handys screen again!

I tried "right click",  open with  java TM SE binary but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `java -jar droidAtScreen-1.0.1.jar` from a command line?

Comment: I did... I get this message: "Error: Unable to access jarfile droidAtScreen-1.0.1.jar", just to be sure, my droidAtScreen-1.0.1.jar has been on my desktop since I downloaded and it has worked perfectly well doest matter where it was......
What do you think it could be Anders??

Comment: Right... You of course need to `cd` to the Desktop folder in the command prompt, or prefix with the full path.

Comment: yessss!!!!!! if I put the full Path it does run!!!
but as soon as i close the cmd console is my droidAtScreen-1.0.1.jar gone!! what should I write on the Variable Systems so I can again run my droidAtScreen-1.0.1.jar just by clicking on it..????
THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

Your co-work might have changed the **class path variable**.
Try running :

```
java -jar //fullPath to your jarfile including jar name
```

or try resetting your classpath as

```
set CLASSPATH="/fullPath to your jarfile.jar"
```

Comment: I have checked on my Systems Variables and I have this:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05 
and

Path=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Diffuse;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Users\perej\android-sdks\tools