# didn't success to run jar file through CMD or Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

i have created a project by eclipse and then a jar file called test.jar. 
Now i try to run the file by cmd or terminal (i have both mac and pc):

```
java -jar test.jar
```

Every time i get this massage:

```
Unable to access jarfile test.jar
```

Of course I installed the JDK already. 
I read about class path but can't find a solution for this annoying problem

maybe someone know how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe permission issues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1238173/3111870

Comment: If it's from eclipse, you want to export a runnable jar.

Comment: yes. I export a runnable jar already