# I have built a jar file using maven, but cannot execute it using the "java" command in linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, jar, executable-jar

thanks in advance for the help!

To clarify my problem:

1) I have an ec2-instance and wrote a java program. I've called it HelloWorld.java

2) I've built a jar file for HelloWorld.java called hello.jar using maven. I used a random pom file with some random dependencies since I figured HelloWorld doesn't need a pom file other than to give the jar file a name.

3) I've been using a spark-submit script to submit apps, but the app I am now trying to run does not have spark involved in it and I want to also deploy it in an environment where spark is not involved. **So I want to submit the app using the "java" command.** I am not sure if I should be submitting the jar file, the .java file, etc. I've seen that I have to give it a .class argument. I'm not sure what to put?

4) My next step is having a java program that has a set of 4 jars dependencies. I would love to know how I can add the 4 jar files as an argument for the "java" command.

**EDIT** @Ascalonian

I tried John Skeets answer and got this exception when I tried the jar command:

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:393)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:182)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:52)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:151)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1149)
```

**EDIT 2** John Skeet's answer ended up working when I recreated the solution. No idea what changed, but it worked. Thanks for the help!

Thanks!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a Manifest in your `jar`?

Comment: For more help, you can look at John Skeet's answer to [How to run a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Comment: @Ascalonian I do not have a manifest in my jar. Unless maven adds it for me? How would I go about adding a Manifest in my jar?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your jar an executable one and add manifest to it:

Something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>theMainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Refer: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: Do I add this in the pom file? Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding this code plus a <plugins> </plugins> before/after in the pom file and it did not work as plugins was not recognized. How do I add the above to a jar file?

Comment: you need to put plugins inside the build process: <build><plugins><plugin>...</build>