# How to run a java file outside of NetBeans that doesnt have a gui?

Tags: java, netbeans, jcreator

Hello I am currently writing a calculator of sorts that I want to let my friends use however I can not find out how to get it to run outside of NetBeans or Jcreator. I have made a .jar file and tried to attach a .bat file to it but none of this has worked. I would like it to run in a cmd sort of window like it does while in Jcreator. Any help welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What does the `.bat` file have to do with this... Anyway, did you package the JAR?  Did you try to execute it with `java -jar <name-of-jar>.jar`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Comment: I read somewhere that to start it you need that and yes it is a jar file. I have not tried that Makoto because I don't know how to do that.