# Java include jar file command line

Tags: java, command-line, jar

Hi this is simple question yet I can't do it.
Just wondering how can I include jarfile on command line?

For example :

My jarfile located at C:\Test\jars\thisonejar.jar

And I'm currently in C:\Test\jars

I set the classpath in C:\Test\jars

How can I include that jar file on command line?

1st line

```
javac Test.java
```

2nd line

```
java Test
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `set classpath=C:\Test\jars\thisonejar.jar;`

or you can include your jar files using the "-cp" option.

`javac -cp ".;/test/jars/thisonejar.jar;" Test.java`

Instead of "-cp" you could also use "-classpath"

`javac -classpath ".;/test/jars/mail.jar;" Test.java`

Comment: Sweet! I'm trying this set classpath=C:\Test\jars\thisone.jar I just missed the semicolon! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, this will add all your jar files from classpath

```
java -cp *:. Test
```