# Launch jar without wrapping (launch4j)

Tags: java, jar, launch4j

Referring to the documentation of launch4j (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) it should be possible to only launch the Java jar without wrapping it to an exe file!

How is this possible? (which command / command arguments)

Thx!

Comment: On windows include a manifest (with Main-Class:) in jar, install a JRE and double click it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Comment: @PetterFriberg It is necessary to do the job with launch4j -> no java -jar (Java Jre is installed but I need the launch4j process) It should be possible.

Comment: try to clarify in what way do you need the launch4j process.. setting variables?, bundle jre.... either you use it or you do not?? Can't really understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: first of all you need to add Main-Class in your manifest then build the jar as mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file

Second way is use the eclipse to build the Runnable jar. and and pass the Main class name while creating it.