# how to run jar files from command prompt

Tags: java, jar

I have executable jar file and want to run from command line along with the   environment variable path as a parameter. In eclipse the code is running well by   setting up the path variable in eclipse configuration.Please help.The command that i am trying is given below

> java -jar jar_name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Comment: Hi, the question needs to be clarified firstly. It *does* look like a duplicate according to the incomplete title. But it asks for something *more* - probably how to get to the environment PATH in the jar's code. It's very simple then: just call `System.getenv("PATH")` in your code. No need to pass the PATH explicitly in command line, which is dependent on the OS where you run it.

Answer (score 4):

```
java -jar jar_name.jar -DsystemVariableName=value
```

Access this value in the code as `System.getProperty("systemVariableName");`

Environment variable can be directly accessed in the code as `System.getEnv("EnvVarName");`

Refer : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()

Comment: This is surely not the correct answer, because provided that the OP really asked for setting a system variable, the `-DsystemVariableName=value` needs to go *before* the `-jar` option - see [documentation for java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). Moreover, I think the question needs to be clarified first - see my comment.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do:

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

`java -jar jarfile.jar` is the shortest answer possible but note that there are multiple things that maybe need to be set for the jar to run correctly as you may need to specify the **Main** class or the **classpath**.

This [*Oracle* tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) will help.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below link. It has all the information you need
http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-.Jar-Java-File.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar <jar.file> <parameter>
```

you can define multiple parameters.