# How can I run my local maven project on another machine?

Tags: java, maven

I created a small maven project for a couple selenium automation tests and need to run them on another machine. How would I go about this?

Comment: Did you read what Maven is? What is the issue?

Comment: @Tunaki sorry I am new to this and trying to get a better understanding. If I were to copy over the project on a drive and then run them on another machine with maven installed it would still run correctly right?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of using Maven: having a reproducible build on every machine.

Answer (score 1):

build a jar out of the maven project and run the jar file.

- you can go through the following [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) to understand how to build a jar.
- for running a jar file check out the following [running a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)