# Will all dependencies packaged in jar or war in maven build?

Tags: maven, jar, war

I am new to maven, I have multi level project where too many dependencies are required. I have have multiple doubts regarding packaging.

1. Is all 3rd party dependencies will packaged in jar or war ? Specifically in jar ?
2. I have built the war and jars in local system and want to deploy them in production environments. So my question is do I need to install maven in production servers also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends on your application type. You can package all your dependencies in a jar file. A .war file is rather a different archive which is used to package a web application that can be deployed on any servlet/jsp container. To bundle your dependencies into a single .jar, Look at [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)
2. A .jar can be executed without maven. This [StackOverlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file) has detail discussion about how to run a Jar file.

Comment: Based on microservice idea it is recommended to start a single self containing jar in a container...which can accomplished by using maven-shade-plugin as well. And it is not a good idea to put Maven into a container  which runs the application...and running an application with Maven in production does not makes sense...The deployment is something different than building...