# Could not find or load default class

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I try to using Runtime but have some problem. I want to use `Runtime.exec("java -cp")`. One is jar file, another is class file. Class file is refer to jar file but not included. Below is my code

```
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;

    System.out.println(Run.class.getResource("").getPath());
    try {
        proc = rt.exec("java -cp c:/data/hh.jar; com/list/shark/Whale");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result is "could not find or load default class". I really want to know that where is location executing runtime and how sole this problem.

PS In local cmd, command is working.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted. Don't post pictures of text: post the text. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is wrong.

For running a jar from command line:

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

If you did not create a manifest file in your jar, `java -jar` will not work.
Then you will need to specify the FQP (fully-qualified classpath) explicitely in the command:

```
java -cp <fully.qualified.class.path>
```

There is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238173/579580) on how to create and run jar that you might want to check out

Comment: yes command is working in cmd but don't working in java runtime I really know about that

Comment: what is the exact exception thrown?

Comment: @ho9 I think you need to have an administrator access. Try compiling the project to jar and grant it an admin access and see if that works.

Comment: @ho9 That command is not working at all. You need to change the slashes to dots.

Answer (score 0):

I post answer for someone who have same trouble

just do

```
 RunTime.exec("cmd /c dir");
```

It is for find out executing current path

and change from exec(command) to exec(command,env,file).

create fileand input executing current path

```
 File file = new File("c:/Test/");

 RunTime.exec("java -cp c:/data/hh.jar; com.list.shark.Whale",null,file);
```

this is success for execute class File referencing other jar file.

Comment: What does `cmd /c dir` have to do with it? All it does is tell you the value of `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, and you don't need to exec anything for that.