# Uncaught error from thread shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem

Tags: jvm, akka, actor, leveldb

I am running an assembly jar file in command prompt and getting the exception below. And resulting in termination.

> Uncaught error from thread [ccp-akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher-23] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[ccp]

There is nothing else running in my windows machine while this.
No code access is there except a jar file.
What might be the issue, i tried restarting the machine a couple of times.
Looks like the issue is only with my machine since it is running fine in all other machines. Even i cross checked all the environmental variables.

Attached the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable for my windows machine, that solved my issue. [Reference](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni/issues/25).

The Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installs runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries required to run applications developed with Visual C++ on a computer that does not have Visual C++ 2010 installed.

Download link [here (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632).

Answer (score 3):

What it says that there is a missing binary dependency, leveldbjni, which interfaces with native/platform specific version of leveldb.

Adding leveldbjni-all to your dependencies as described in the docs (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.0/scala/persistence.html#id8) should solve that, if it doesn't then maybe the platform is unsupported (which seems weird, the leveldbjni homepage lists both win32 and win64 as supported - https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni)

Comment: But I cant add any dependencies, since I just have a jar file to run.

Comment: You can still run the jar file with extra other jar files on the class path, see this answer for details on how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file

Comment: I opened the Jar file and found the leveldb dependencies were there and tried adding extra files as above still same issue @johanandren

Answer (score 2):

Step1: Go To "C:\Users\asaini75" and  Delete already existing folder  ".datastax_studio"

Step2: Go To  "C:\Users\asaini75\Downloads\datastax-studio-6.0.0\bin" and click on "server" windows batch file and Wait until you see the below message on your command prompt.

[image]

Step3: Go To browser and hit the URL  "http://localhost:9091". You will below the home page.

[image]

Step4: Add connection and Notebook. it will work perfectly fine.