# List modules in jar file

Tags: java, jar, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I've created what I'm pretty sure is a modular jar file. But if possible, I'd like to double check. Given a jar file, is there a way to determine what modules the compiler would find within it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The alternative is to use the jar `--describe-module` (`-d` for short), e.g.:

```
jar --file=myjar.jar --describe-module
```

Answer (score 16):

You can list the modules within the jar using the following [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624) tool command:-

```
java -p yourModular.jar --list-modules
```

***Edit***: You shall preferably make use of the `jar` command lin as suggested in [@Alan's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46617956/1746118)

Comment: I recommend to [use  `jar --describe-module`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46617956/2525313) instead - it's much more precise and contains more relevant information.

Comment: This way is handy for checking which modules are built into the runtime image (say as built using jlink/jpackage) with `java --list-modules`.

Answer (score -4):

To extract the contents of a JAR file to see what’s inside, change the extension of the JAR from `.jar` to `.zip`. Then you can extract the files with whatever zip extraction tool you choose.

Comment: I know how to extract the jar. I was wondering if there was an easier way to determine what modules it contains than poring over the source files.

Comment: Modules? Do you mean external libraries?

Comment: No, modules as in Java 9 modules, aka project Jigsaw…

Comment: I’m sorry, I’ve never worked in Java 9. I misunderstood the question. I don’t know if any way to do what you are asking.