# module-info.java for SWT cross-platform maven project

Tags: java, maven, swt, java-module

On Windows package `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64` is used, while for Linux build it's `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64`.

1. If nothing is specified in `module-info.java`, error message is `java: package org.eclipse.swt does not exist`
2. If in `module-info.java` both are specified:

   ```
   requires org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64;
   requires org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64;
   ```

   error message: `module ... reads package org.eclipse.swt from both org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 and org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64`
3. If only one `requires` is specified, then project works only on one platform.

What would be correct setup for `module-info.java`, so that project would run on both platforms?

Comment: It isn't really possible to build a single SWT app that will run on all platforms, you need a separate build for each platform.

Comment: I'm using different build profiles in maven, so based on platform (unix/windows) corresponding SWT dependency is added. This works until trying to add `module-info.java`.

Comment: There was a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65539331/2670892), the answer just uses `requires swt;` Not sure it really addresses cross platform.

Comment: Is this just an SWT app or is it an Eclipse based RCP? [tag:tycho] is used for RCP builds and understands cross platform.

Comment: It's standalone SWT app. Using just `requires swt;` gives `module not found: swt`, so some additional setup may be required for this case. But it's not clear to me what this additional setup may be.

Comment: The answer to the related question seems to go through the setup in detail, have you looked at that.?

Comment: It looks like that `requires swt` in linked answer comes from `swt.jar`, that was in downloaded zip file. As I'm using SWT builds from maven, my module names are as specified in question. 

My question would be how to specify `requires` in `module-info.java`, that would work for both Linux and Windows build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [bug 559162](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=559162) in SWT. Their Automatic-Module-Name in the SWT jar files manifest is impractical.

I suggest to stick to module-less builds (without module-info.java) until this gets fixed.